# dtype used by Google Earth Engine in NPY export

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to export a small amount of data from Google Earth Engine using the NPY format. According to the documentation I should get a NumPy binary format but what is the type of the bands ?

Here is a small example of a download:

```py
import ee 
import numpy as np
import io 
import requests 

ee.Initialize()

AnnualChanges = ee.ImageCollection('projects/JRC/TMF/v1_2021/AnnualChanges').mosaic()
coords = [15.264355, -0.53036]
buffer = ee.Geometry.Point(coords).buffer(90).bounds()

link = AnnualChanges.getDownloadURL({
    'name': 'test',
    'scale': 30,
    'region': buffer,
    'filePerBand': False,
    'format': 'NPY',
})
response = requests.get(link)
response.raise_for_status()
data = np.load(io.BytesIO(response.content))
```

Now from these data if I print the dtype I get the following :

```
[
    ('Dec1990', 'u1'), ('Dec1991', 'u1'), ('Dec1992', 'u1'), ('Dec1993', 'u1'),
    ('Dec1994', 'u1'), ('Dec1995', 'u1'), ('Dec1996', 'u1'), ('Dec1997', 'u1'), 
    # ...
    ('Dec2018', 'u1'), ('Dec2019', 'u1'), ('Dec2020', 'u1'), ('Dec2021', 'u1')
]
```

What is this format and how can get back to the minimal scalar dtype ?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the data type objects you're displaying.  See: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

To get them in a more readable form, just print one:

```
>>> data.dtype[0]
dtype('uint8')
```

Each band will have its own separate data type based on the underlying data.

Comment: but then standard operations are not possible like `data.astype(int)` my only workaround at the moment is to go back and forth with a list `np.array(data.tolist())`